# "page not found" when using HTTPS

Tags: asp.net-mvc

When navigating to the CheckOut page with HTTPS I am getting an error that the page is not found.

I am geeing the same error on every page I changing manually from HTTP to HTTPS

Port 443 is allocated for this website on my server.

This what I have in the controller:

```
#if !DEBUG
    [RequireHttps]
#endif
    public ViewResult Checkout()
    {             
        return View();
    }
```

Do I need to add something to the route config?

Comment: I suspect that the problem has nothing to do with ASP.NET MVC but with the way you have configured your IIS server and the SSL certificate. Are you able to access your website through HTTPS when you navigate to `https://mysite.com`?

Comment: No, I cannot! You are right!

Comment: So then your question should be posted on http://serverfault.com as it is not programming related but server configuration related. Feel free to delete this post which is off-topic here.